# Can 'floccinaucinihilipilification' be considered a real word?

Tags: nouns, is-it-a-word

Can 'floccinaucinihilipilification' still be considered a real word?

The only context that I have ever seen it used is as an example of one of the longest words in the English language.

Also how would you use it in a sentence?

Do we have to use literally in a context where estimating somethings value is being done, or can it be used more metaphorically where it is argued that something is meaningless (ie has no useful value (like arguing a word is useless)).

Comment: [What is the longest word in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5528/longest-word-in-english). I don't understand OP's *"**still** be considered"* - it never was "the longest" anyway. Also note that OED specifically notes it as a **humorous** coinage (first recorded 1741).

Comment: Related: [Why does my spellchecker vindicate “floccinaucinihilipilification”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30828/10041)

Comment: Floccinaucinihilipilification may well be an (artificially?) embiggened word but it's not especially cromulent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Also how would you use it in a sentence?

I once did use it in a sentence. I was negotiating a deal for the sale of some baseball cards. The buyer was concerned that the cards might be fake. Another person looked over the cards, but I knew he tended to consider cards fake even if they were 100% genuine. (Natural variation on older cards can make them look 'trimmed' but the machines those days made irregular cuts and not all cards were the same size.) He pronounced a T204 Ramly trimmed (and thus worthless). I demanded he cease his floccinaucinihilipilification. The buyer snorted soda out of his nose.

I consider it one of the greatest things I ever said. Better than when I told an extremely ugly woman who was talking about how much she loved nature that I considered this surprising considering that nature clearly hadn't returned the favor.

Comment: +1 for being able to pronounce it, much less use it in a non-forced context.

Comment: I hope it didn't go all over the card.

Answer (score 4):

In its entry on *[floccinaucinihilipilification](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/floccinaucinihilipilification?region=us&q=floccinaucinihilipilification)*, Oxford Dictionaries notes that "the word is used chiefly as a curiosity."

(Note the largely contrived attempts at usage [here](http://wordnik.com/words/floccinaucinihilipilification).)

Comment: I think it would be wrong to flocci-pauci-nihili-pilificate the humourous possibilities of using the word. Then of course, it used to serve a useful purpose in preventing some other word from being the longest word in the Concise Oxford.

Answer (score 3):

> Also how would you use it in a sentence?

Can 'floccinaucinihilipilification' still be considered a real word?

Comment: [Use, not mention.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)

Answer (score 0):

[OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=floccinaucinihilipilification&ls=a) finds 15 dictionaries with English definitions that include the word *floccinaucinihilipilification*.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=floccinaucinihilipilification) has also an entry for it:

> "action or habit of estimating as worthless," 1741, a combination of
>   four Latin words (*flocci, nauci, nihili, pilifi*) all signifying "at
>   a small price" or "for nothing," which were listed together in a rule
>   of the well-known Eton Latin Grammar. The kind of jocular formation
>   that was possible among educated men in Britain in those days. Just
>   so, *as in praesenti*, the opening words of mnemonic lines on
>   conjugation in Lilley's 16c. Latin grammar, could stand alone as late
>   as 19c. and be understood to mean "rudiments of Latin."